# How to run e2e tests automatically?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, testng, e2e-testing

I really don't know how to ask question to Google about this, so I excuse me that it is naive.

Our team is developing SPA application in `ReactJS`. We also do back-end programming for `NodeJS`. Our project recently got more e2e tests. They are written using `webdriver.io` packages. Everything works as expected but circa `30 tests run about 50 minutes`. It is too long to pause developer work and force him to run tests.

We came with the idea that now when we have so many tests, we need to run them on separate computer (other than a  developer's laptop, further I call it e2e-laptop).

So I programmed a bash script and installed Ubuntu on a e2e-laptop. My idea is, that developer who wants to run e2e test logs in on e2e-laptop with ssh, runs specified script with arguments (eg: --rev= specific git revision the tests should run on, --email= where to send Allure report) and logs out. After tests are done he gets `Allure` report in his mailbox.
This all sounds to me OK, but not very well. It works - it is like a dirty MVP. But what I really would like to give my team is the web browser based UI that gives the features my script has. I can imagine this software is hosted on e2e-laptop, every developer can open its webpage address in his local browser. Then after authorization, there are options: run all specs, run chosen specs, send report and more. It would be the best if that software could also allow simultaneous running of tests commissioned by multiple developers.

What software I need?

Answer (score 1):

You need a continuous integration tool. https://stackify.com/top-continuous-integration-tools/

I recommend Jenkins.

Comment: Our CI tool is Pipelines from Bitbucket, but it is the core of our deployment to different environments and we don't want to couple it with long running e2e tests. Another problem your answers has, that there is no environment on Pipelines to run Web Browser. On the other side Jenkins is just a tool to run such scripts that I wrote, so this would be just another way of running my script

Comment: And thanks for the link to that summary, there is more than 50 applications and one could be the one :)

Answer (score 1):

I would first try to run your selenium tests headless in a docker container on your laptop. Once you are able to do that, use that same configuration in your docker container running in Bitbucket pipelines. It could actually be the same container and the same scripts. Then, developers can just make a branch and work with the tests on that branch. If only a certain subset of tests need to run, then the developer can make the necessary changes on his or her local branch to run those tests and push it up to Bitbucket. This should help with the configuration https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium.